# Wordpress base page error

Tags: settings, base-page

I need help with base pages for wordpress.

I am getting a civicrm system error:

**CiviCRM relies upon a base page in WordPress, but it is not published.**

On the setting page, there is the text:

**By default, CiviCRM will generate front-facing pages using the home page at https://idahonativeplants.org/ as its base. If you want to use a different template for CiviCRM pages, set the path here.**

The base page is set to the default home page of the site. I do not understand why I get this error, the page most definitely is published.

Wordpress Version 5.5.1
CiviCRM 5.29.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That message is misleading and we'll need to fix that.   Using the home page as the base page just won't work.  A WP Page needs to be created and set as the base page.

There should be (depending on your version) a System Alert that reads:

```
CiviCRM relies upon a base page in WordPress at http://example.org/, but it is missing. The default is https://example.org/civicrm, which does exist on this site. You can set the correct base page in the WordPress integration settings.
```

CiviCRM needs a WP page set as the basepage.  This should be set in `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/uf&reset=1`  New installs create 'civicrm' as a WP Page and set that as the basepage.